# Python : How to continue execution inside a try statement after an exception stop it

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

In my application, I'm loading some data from a file. This can fail and raise an exception. As a consequence, I want to log a WARNING and continue to load next data.

I'm doing it like that :

```
try:
    data_A = getDefaultConf(param_1,param_2)
except Exception as e:
    log(WARNING, "Failed to get default parametres: "+str(e))
try:
    data_B = getDefaultConf(param_1,param_3)
except Exception as e:
    log(WARNING, "Failed to get default parametres: "+str(e))
try:
    data_C = getDefaultConf(param_4,param_5)
except Exception as e:
    log(WARNING, "Failed to get default parametres: "+str(e))
try:
    data_D = getDefaultConf(param_4,param_6)
except Exception as e:
    log(WARNING, "Failed to get default parametres: "+str(e))
try:
    data_E = getDefaultConf(param_4,param_7)
except Exception as e:
    log(WARNING, "Failed to get default parametres: "+str(e))
```

It works but looks heavy. So, my question is: does it exist a way to do it lighter?
It could be something working like that:

```
try:
    data_A = getDefaultConf(param_1,param_2)
    data_B = getDefaultConf(param_1,param_3)
    data_C = getDefaultConf(param_4,param_5)
    data_D = getDefaultConf(param_4,param_6)
    data_E = getDefaultConf(param_4,param_7)
except Exception as e:
    log(WARNING, "Failed to get default parametres: "+str(e))
    # Here something that could work like a "continue" statement so that if loading of
    #  data_2 fails it will store the log and continue by trying to load data_3, etc.
```

I ever saw some answers in other posts suggesting to put it in the loop but, would not it be heavier to manage my parametres?

I'm waiting for any suggestion in this way. Whatever the case my code is working. So, it's just a question of curiosity on a problem that could also help other programmers...

Comment: What does *heavy* and *light* even mean?

Comment: @Klaus Byskov Hoffmann: Imagine if the amount of data grows up ... there is a very long repetition in my first example! Sorry but i don't know how to explain it with a better word in english (maybe tedious or tiresome)

Comment: All answers are interesting; thanks for all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case I might introduce a new function (assuming you can't or don't want to change the existing `getDefaultConf`):

```
def getDefault(x, y):
    try:
        return getDefaultConf(x,y)
    except Exception as e:
        log(WARNING, "Failed to get default parametres: "+str(e))
    return None

data_A = getDefault(param_1,param_2)
data_B = getDefault(param_1,param_3)
data_C = getDefault(param_4,param_5)
data_D = getDefault(param_4,param_6)
data_E = getDefault(param_4,param_7)
```

The only difference here is that you'll get `None` back for calls that result in an exception. This may or may not be acceptable for your application.

Comment: -1 because you just solved the problem without thinking about how to improve the original code. Having variable names with an enumeration is always an indication to use a container instead. See @shawn-chin's answer how it could look like.

Comment: I don't think we know whether this is the *actual* code, or whether it's an example with a bunch of placeholder variable names. I assumed the latter. Anyway, the OP didn't ask about data representation, the question is about exception handling. I kept the general structure of the code the same so that other changes such as using a container wouldn't obscure my point.

Comment: Anyway, there is a mapping between the variables and the parameters. So the logical step is to use actually one.

Comment: what a nice use case for a decorator!

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way:

```
params = {
    "A": (param_1, param_2),
    "B": (param_1, param_3),
    "C": (param_4, param_5),
    "D": (param_4, param_6),
    "E": (param_4, param_7),
}
data = {}

for key, args in params.items():
    try:
        data[key] = getDefaultConf(*args)
    except Exception as e:
        log(WARNING, "Failed to get default parametres: "+str(e))
```

The only difference here is that the results will now be accessible via the data dict, e.g. `data["A"]`.

Do note that when an exception is raised by `getDefaultConf()`, the associated entry will not be included into the dict -- this can be a good or a bad thing depending on how you're planning to use the data.

If you do need a default value when no value is assigned, you can use `data.get("A", None)`.

Comment: +1 Exactly my thoughts. Variables with continued names are always an indicator to use a container instead.

Answer (score 1):

Put your try except inside the method.This would do it.

```
def getDefaultConf(param_1,param_2):
    try:
        #code
    except  Exception as e:
        log(WARNING, "Failed to get default parametres: "+str(e))
```

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann Another check is necessary anyway if only a warning is emitted after the exception.